# How extract multiplelinks from single cell (Googlesheets)?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How extract multiplelinks from single cell(Googlesheets,GooglesheetsAPI) in Python?

[image]

`service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

```
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    print(result)`
```

We tried to get links with this code, but this doesnt work, tried with FORMULA but the same thing
I need to get all hyperlinks in single cell

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve multiple hyperlinks from a cell using googleapis for python.

In the current stage, "Method: spreadsheets.values.get" cannot retrieve the hyperlinks. In this case, "Method: spreadsheets.get" is required to be used. When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```py
spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

fields = "sheets(data(rowData(values(textFormatRuns(format(link),startIndex),hyperlink,userEnteredValue))))"
res = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=[sheetName], fields=fields).execute()
rowData = res.get("sheets", [])[0].get("data", [])[0].get("rowData", [])
res = []
for i, r in enumerate(rowData):
    values = r.get("values", [])
    if values and values != []:
        for j, c in enumerate(values):
            if "hyperlink" in c:
                res.append({"rowIndex": i, "colIndex": j, "value": c.get(
                    "userEnteredValue", {}), "hyperlinks": [c.get("hyperlink", "")]})
            elif "textFormatRuns" in c:
                textFormatRuns = c.get("textFormatRuns", [])
                temp = []
                for t in textFormatRuns:
                    uri = t.get("format", {}).get(
                        "link", {}).get("uri", "")
                    temp.append(uri)
                res.append({"rowIndex": i, "colIndex": j, "value": c.get(
                    "userEnteredValue", {}), "hyperlinks": temp})
print(res)
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. `rowIndex` and `colIndex` are the indexes from the cell "A1". When the cell "A1", those values are 0 and 0, respectively.

```json
[
  {
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "colIndex": 1,
    "value": {"stringValue": "sample1"},
    "hyperlinks": ["https://###"]
  },
  {
    "rowIndex": 3,
    "colIndex": 1,
    "value": {"stringValue": "sample1, sample2, sample3"},
    "hyperlinks": ["https://###", "", "https://###", "", "https://###"]
  }
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is a simple script for explaining this answer. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: @Decard Cain About `Thanks for your advice! this part works perfectly!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer