Get access to hyperlinks which was added in UI
I'm trying to get access to all hyperlinks in my sheet using python and gsheet api v4. But fields='sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink' is not working, valueRenderOption=FORMULA not working because there is no formulas in cells:
for sheet in spreadsheet.get('sheets'):
     sheet_id = sheet['properties']['sheetId']
     sheet_data = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().get(
     spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=sheet['properties']['title'],            fields='sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink').execute()
     values = sheet_data.get('values', [])`

But values return list of lists with cells text.

This thread might be an answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76374394
